# Property or indexer cannot be assigned to "--" it is read only

Tags: c#, string, readonly

So I'm trying to pass a local string to another form in a c# project. This is my code:

Form 1:

```
...
Main frm = new Main();
frm.Passvalue = usrTxt.Text;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Form 2

```
...
public string Username;
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Property or indexer "Main.Passvalue" cannot be assigned to "--" it is read only

I never declared anything as `ReadOnly`, does anyone know what the problem here is?

Comment: I that is because you haven't specified `set` property for `Passvalue`

Answer (score 23):

It has no setter, which makes it a readonly property, change it to:

```
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
    set { Username = value; }
}
```

Incidentally, this seems a little redundant, as you're publicly exposing `Username` anyway. It's generally considered good practice to make class fields private.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to *set* your property, you have to add an *set* handler:

```
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
    set { Username = value; }
}
```

It would be easier though to use auto-implemented properties right away:

```
public string Username
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you only have a *getter* for `Form2.Passvalue`, but no *setter*. Add this in `Form2`:

```
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
    set { Username = value; } // add this setter
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Property doesn't have setter.

Here is code you can use for Auto-implemented getters and setters.

```
public string Username { get; set; } 
public string Passvalue { get; set; }
```

Or if you want to get and set value of UserName from Passvalue, you can use

```
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
    set { Username = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your property misses setter. Change it to:

```
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
    set { Username = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by many others, you need to permit a value to be set for the property `Username`. This can be done in several ways:

Probably the simplest - just ad a `get;`:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
```

You can use the expanded version, as shown in other answers here, but I think that only makes sense if you want to add some kind of logic to it (permitted from C# 7.0 and onwards):

```
private string passValue; 
public string Passvalue
{
    get { return Username; }
    set { this.passValue = value ?? "MysteriousStranger"; }
}
```

#### New in C# 9: *Init Only* Setters

You might not want to permit the property to be changed after creation. For that purpose, C# 9 adds *init only* setters. These will allow you to set the value only when the object is instantiated. In your case it should allow you to do the following:

```
// Declare the prop using INIT instead of SET:
public string Username { get; init; }

// Now you can set the value of the property as you initiate 
// the frm object. 
Main frm = new Main(){ Passvalue = usrTxt.Text; };

// Trying to change the value later would cause a compile time error:
// frm.Passvalue = "whatever";     

frm.ShowDialog();
```